# Select count: comparing two queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries.

The first is an older query Non-ANSI

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ses) 
FROM
    (SELECT
         sa.ses, sa.att, sa.ser, 
         ccp.sta, ccp.end,
         c.id_, c.per, c.is_,
         ccp.clt_
     FROM 
         sa, tn, ccp, cp, c,
         (SELECT DISTINCT sa.ses
          FROM sa, sapa
          WHERE sa.ses = sapa.ses
            AND sapa.pro IN (61,62)
            AND sa.full >= to_date('1/1/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')) sapa1
     WHERE 
         1=1
         AND sa.ses = sapa1.ses (+)
         AND sa.ses = tn.ses
         AND ccp.cli = c.cli
         AND c.cus = sa.pro
         AND substr(c.hea,1,1) = 'H'
         AND sa.ful >= ccp.sta
         AND sa.ful < nvl(ccp.end('9/9/9000','mm/dd/yyyy'))
         AND sa.ful >= to_date('1/1/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
         AND sa.ful <= sysdate
         AND ccp.cli = cp.cli
         AND cp.clie = 1
         AND sa.proj <> 'MMA'
         AND c.pers IS NOT NULL)
```

The second I rewrote as ANSI

```
 SELECT COUNT(SES) FROM (
 SELECT
 SA.FUL,
 SA.SES,
 SA.ATT,
 SA.SER,
CCP.STA,
CCP.END,
C.ID_,
C.PER,
C.IS_,
CCP.CLT,
SAPA1.PRO,
SAPA1.SES

FROM SESSION_ALL SA

LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
        SA.SES,
        SA.CLT,
        SAPA.SES,
        SAPA.PRO
        ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY SA.SES ORDER BY SAPA.SES DESC) RNK
        FROM  SA
        INNER JOIN SAPA ON SA.SES = SAPA.SES
        WHERE 1=1               
          AND SAPA.PRO IN (61,62)                         
          AND SA.FUL >= TO_DATE('1/1/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
                                                           )SAPA1 

             ON SA.SES      = SAPA1.SES AND SAPA1.RNK = 1   
 INNER JOIN TN    ON SA.SES    = TN.SES                           
 INNER JOIN CCP   ON SA.CLT    = CCP.CLT
 INNER JOIN C     ON CCP.CLI   = C.CLI
 INNER JOIN CP    ON CCP.CLI   = CP.CLI                                     

WHERE 1=1
 AND C.PER IS NOT NULL
AND SUBSTR(C.HEA,1,1) = 'H'
AND CP.CLI = 1
AND SA.PRO <> 'MMA'
AND SA.FUL >= CCP.STA
AND SA.FUL < NVL(CCP.END('9/9/9000','MM/DD/YYYY'))
AND SA.FUL >= TO_DATE('1/1/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND SA.FUL <= SYSDATE                               
         )
```

When I remove the count from both they both come back with results very quickly. It's when I add the count that the 2nd query does not return results, it just continues to run. The non-ANSI (first query) returns results very quickly. ANy idea why this happens? I'm not familar with the execute plan

Execute Plan 1st Query: (non ANSI)
[image]

Execute Plan 2nd Query: (NEW)
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the two `FROM` clauses queries yield equivalent results? `LEFT JOIN` is hard to see with implicit joins over explicit joins.

Comment: When you run without the count, is it returning *all* rows int he result set quickly, or just the first page? And are the two full result sets identical? We'd probably need to see the explain plans for both queries to be able to see what it's doing differently.

Comment: IMHO is the subselect in the frist query complete useless, it has no effect on the resultset (no culumns selected and becasue of the outer join and the distinct it can't add or remove rows). In the second query the subselect is hard work.

Comment: Well, it's not just a simple rewrite, is it; you're getting different data and have different join conditions, so the execution plans will be different anyway...

Comment: @AlexPoole I get the same result set count when i add a where clause for between dates. I haven't compared the full dataset. I have also attached the execute plan.

Comment: It looks like you need indexes on the join columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can simplify these queries a lot.

The following query should give you the same count as the second query would if it finished. I don't think you need the SAPA1 inline view at all because you are counting SA.SES and outer joining SAPA1 to that. You can also just count the rows (using count(*)) instead because you are inner joining on the column you are trying to count (this removes nulls automatically).

Try it out and see what you get. I can't test it myself unless you provide me with some dummy data using these tables.

```
select count(*)

FROM SESSION_ALL SA

 INNER JOIN TN    ON SA.SES    = TN.SES                           
 INNER JOIN CCP   ON SA.CLT    = CCP.CLT
 INNER JOIN C     ON CCP.CLI   = C.CLI
 INNER JOIN CP    ON CCP.CLI   = CP.CLI                                     

WHERE C.PER IS NOT NULL
AND SUBSTR(C.HEA,1,1) = 'H'
AND CP.CLI = 1
AND SA.PRO <> 'MMA'
AND SA.FUL >= CCP.STA
AND SA.FUL < NVL(CCP.END('9/9/9000','MM/DD/YYYY'))
AND SA.FUL >= TO_DATE('1/1/2013','MM/DD/YYYY')
AND SA.FUL <= SYSDATE
```

Here is what the first query would look like in the same formatting. Although I personally prefer ANSI joins.

```
SELECT count(*)
 FROM 
     sa, tn, ccp, cp, c
 WHERE 
     sa.ses = tn.ses
     AND ccp.cli = c.cli
     AND c.cus = sa.pro
     AND substr(c.hea,1,1) = 'H'
     AND sa.ful >= ccp.sta
     AND sa.ful < nvl(ccp.end('9/9/9000','mm/dd/yyyy'))
     AND sa.ful >= to_date('1/1/2013','mm/dd/yyyy')
     AND sa.ful <= sysdate
     AND ccp.cli = cp.cli
     AND cp.clie = 1
     AND sa.proj <> 'MMA'
     AND c.pers IS NOT NULL
```